# will gaming destroy my phone battery?

Tags: battery

I think games probably destroyed my Note 2 battery. I often play games for hours straight while charging. Last Sunday it was dead with horrible heat. Then I borrowed friend's mpj backup battery, swapped it, and everything worked perfectly again.
Now I have ordered a new battery online. I am not sure if playing games while charging could destroy the battery, if so, i swear wont do it again.

Comment: If you operate something at its limits permanently, damage is to be expected. Imagine driving your car at full throttle, and not even stopping for fuel; that's about what you did here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Charging and playing heavy games damages the battery very quickly. It is caused due to the overheating while charging, short Recharge n discharge cycles while charging n playing games and heat due to the GPU. Heat is the sole enemy of Battery. This is the same scenario in most of the mobile devices.

I recommend you to first fully charge the device n play until the charge drains out. I know it's a bit harsh.

Comment: Worth noting that staff in some of the battery makers are advised to charge their laptops to around 80% and start charging around 40%! The batteries in smart phones don't have 'memory' and as you said HEAT is a battery killer. Plugging in and running games (especially on Samsung devices) causes a LOT of heat. The CPU/GPU are made to run hot, but the battery is NOT. Charge it up and play unplugged as the poster above said!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using your phone while charging as this can cause your phone to overheat. Also when you are using your phone while charging what actually happens is that the amount of time the battery actually requires for being fully charged increases due to simultaneous consumption. This can also cause the battery to swell and even hurt its life in longer run.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say as such anything. If u use ur phone for hours, you might probably destroy your battery. So the conclusion is:-
Not only games destroy your battery, any other app can also destroy ( Condition is that if u use it for hours and get used to)